# Click on Paypal button with selenium not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, paypal

I have a problem with Selenium and I cannot press this PayPal button.

[image]

[image: HTML]

I tried all methods from the Selenium documentation but unfortunately it doesn't press on it. I even used the normal `findElement` method but unfortunately no reaction.

This is my code line right now:

```
await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath('//*[@id="paypal-animation-content"]/div[1]/div'))).click();
```

I'm waiting for the button but it doesn't help either. I also searched for the class with `findElement(By.className)`

Does anyone have experience with it and can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can try using js to click it

```
var xPathPaypal = "xpath goes here"
var paypalButton = driver.FindElementByXPath(xPathPaypal);
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", paypalButton);
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to use the last line. For me it shows an error in the syntax that a bracket is missing and then a semicolon after the 'driver)'. Can you tell me how I can use that in node.js. Do I have to import something first?

Comment: Sorry that was c#, try this 'driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", paypalButton)'